How to use DTMF input in Twilio to call Python function
I have Twilio working with a Python IVR app using a bi-directional websocket connection. DTMF messages from Twilio are used to detect user digit input while the websocket connection is alive. This is working well. However, when I receive and recognize DTMF input, for example the number 1 was pressed, I want to call a Python function and run some code. I want to do this without closing the websocket connection in my Python IVR app. From what I've read in the Twilio documentation and confirmed via testing, Twilio does not execute the next TwiML verb until the bi-directional websocket connection is closed. My code is as follows:
ws.close() // Closes the bi-directional websocket connection in the Python IVR app

// TwiML code that starts the bi-directional websocket connection and calls the number once the connection is closed by the Python IVR app as shown by the code above
<Connect>
    <Stream url="wss://{{ host }}/audio/" />
</Connect>
<Dial>
    <Number>{{ number }}</Number>
</Dial>

This code works as expected when the bi-directional websocket connection is closed. But I would like to dial the number without closing the websocket connection. I have not figured out a way to do this since when I close the websocket, control is passed to the TwiML template and no other Python code can be run.
Any help would be appreciated.

Anyone have any suggestions? Is there a Twilio expert in the house?
